# Adding timeline play button in CARTO Builder?

Tags: carto, timeslider

I am using the new CARTO builder, trying to add a timeline with the time series widget. (something like this one: http://bl.ocks.org/csobier/cebdd47242d7ca98ec5e)

However, a bar chart shows up, which only allows for selection rather than playing the data overtime. I do see a play button in the thumbnail for type selection though, on the upper left corner.

I saw a lot of folks use Torque.js for building timelines, but what I am asking here is, is it possible to add a timeline play button inside the CARTO Builder?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Widgets are only used to **filter** data. If you want to change how the data *looks*, you're going to need to style it. Just...

1) Click on your dataset and go to the STYLE tab.

2) Use the slider to change the AGGREGATION type to ANIMATED.

Animated maps automatically add a time-series widget, which has a special add-on: the play button you're looking for.