# Why doesn't animated show up as an option in Carto Builder Style Tab?

Tags: carto, timeslider, datetime

I'm trying to do a time series in carto.

My data table has the following:


-polygon geometry  (geom)

-polygon name (string)   - eg State name

-category (string)

-date  (datetime)

Someone asked the question I'm looking to answer as [Is it possible to add a timeline play button in CARTO Builder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240520), but even though I have a timedate column, and have been able to add the widget, when I look under the style tab, I don't have the animated option.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

Aggregated styles are only available for point data. Layers containing other geometries, such as lines or polygons, won't show the AGGREGATION options in the STYLE tab.

A possible workaround is to use a *Centroid Analysis* to find the centroids of your polygons, which will result in a point layer, then style that point layer as an animated map.

You can learn more about these analysis in the corresponding CARTO Guides: [Animated Maps](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/animating-maps-with-point-data) and [Find Centroid From Geometries](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/find-centroid-from-geometries#centroid-of-clusters)

Comment: Hi arredond, will there ever be an animated style for polygon geometries?